# Can you debug wordpress console error

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have  500 internal server error problem,which is caused by 1 of my $.post functions.I have enabled wordpress debug and debug_log but nothing really shows because problem isn't with whole wordpress,but with my function(error is showing only in console).So is there a way to enable a debug mode for console errors,i need to read that error in more understandable way.Thanks !

Comment: you have to check in you php file.. requesting is in php file not in jquery

Comment: So if $.post("/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php" is my file path, that mean that there is problem with my page (Food-Groups-BG.php) and not with my function ?

Comment: Probably the webserver configuration prevents display errors. Either you can change this configuration or you have to look in error log from the webserver for a helpful error message.

Comment: if you are getting error on sending post request then this will be a php error on your post request page

Comment: Well the only error on page which i get after i am using $.post method is from a wordpress function to call the header

http://pastebin.com/ARByHNBG

I am confused AF what does header have to do with java function and even with server internal error,sorry if that is stupid,lol #brainfreeze

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug the 500 internal error , check your console is the best option. Also you can enable Wordpress debug to get more ideas about the error.

In sort the error have possible reasons as per the link I have give here :

[How to solve 500 internal error for wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/)

Let first apply the solutions in the given link , let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I have done all things in the like like twice,i got this problem for 6 days already,checked every part of the internet :X.Wordpress debug doesn't works only when there is a problem or crash with wordpress itself,i have debug mode and debug_log enabled but nothing shows there.The error is from my input field for search,this function --http://pastebin.com/0W8Fbwrm  is causing the error in console,wordpress shows nothing in debug log or anywhere else.. ;/

Comment: Can you able to provide a link of the issue?

Comment: Edit:Error is occuring when you start typing in Input field.

((Info for input field):It must excecute a php which will check if there is a letter or combination of letters which you input and display the results.

Comment: It will always give 500 internal error. You can not use ajax like this.

Comment: Please use the ajax from admin-ajax which is default wordpress future : http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

Comment: Let me know if you need help to implement the same future

Comment: I am back at the start....When i give url to only Food-Groups-BG.php it is giving me 404 not found and when i give full path it is giving me 500 Internal server error,EXACTLY the same thing as previous method..I am gonna kill myself mate :X:X What does that thing want here is my new php http://pastebin.com/q5X1GR6m and jquery http://pastebin.com/EFF0L3CC

Comment: Any ideas of what is causing it and how to fix it :?